# Can not select second dynamic div inside a delegate event handler

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'd like change classes of active tabs and rooms when a `chat-tab` is clicked. It is expected to remove `hidden` class from `room` which is not clicked, and also add it to irrelevant divs.

The problem is that whatever I tried I could not get the selectors for rooms to work.

```js
$('.chat-container').on('click', '.chat-tab', (function() {
  activeTab = $('body').data('activeTab');


  //working fine
  $('.chat-tab').removeClass("active");
  $('.chat-tab[data-tab="' + activeTab + '"]').addClass("active");

  var newActiveTab = $(this).attr("data-tab");
  $('body').data('activeTab', newActiveTab);

  //Do not work
  $('.rooms div[id!=' + newActiveTab + '_room]').addClass("hidden");
  $('.rooms div[id=' + newActiveTab + '_room]').removeClass("hidden");

}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chat-container">
  <!--dynamic tabs-->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="chat-bar">
    <li class="chat-tab room-tab active" data-tab="Public"><a data-toggle="pill">Public</a></li>
    <li class="chat-tab" data-tab="Sports"><a data-toggle="pill">Sports</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!--/tabs-->

  <!--dynamic rooms-->
  <div class="rooms">
    <div id="Public_room" class="room hidden">
      <ol id="Public_msgOl" >
        <li>dodo : Hi Pubilc</li>
      </ol>
    </div>

  <div id="Sports_room" class="room hidden">
    <ol id="Sports_msgOl" >
      <li>dodo : Whats up sportsmen?</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
<!--/rooms-->
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update with CSS and fix the obvious errors in the console (activeTab not defined)

Comment: Where/how is activeTab defined?

Comment: @BoltClock  `activeTab = $('body').data('activeTab');` I just added to the snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's true for your case, but finding the name of the activeTab didn't really work for me. The real problem however was your selector for the chat rooms. When you query for ids, you have to surround the value by quotation marks, like this `[id="value"]`.

```js
$('.chat-container').on('click', '.chat-tab', function() {
  activeTab = $("ul .active").attr("data-tab");

  //working fine
  $('.chat-tab').removeClass("active");
  $('.chat-tab[data-tab="' + activeTab + '"]').addClass("active");

  var newActiveTab = $("ul .active").attr("data-tab");
  $('body').data('activeTab', newActiveTab);

  //Do work now
  $(".rooms div[id!='" + newActiveTab + "_room']").addClass("hidden");
  $(".rooms div[id='" + newActiveTab + "_room']").removeClass("hidden");
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chat-container">
  <!--dynamic tabs-->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="chat-bar">
    <li class="chat-tab room-tab active" data-tab="Public"><a data-toggle="pill">Public</a></li>
    <li class="chat-tab" data-tab="Sports"><a data-toggle="pill">Sports</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!--/tabs-->

  <!--dynamic rooms-->
  <div class="rooms">
    <div id="Public_room" class="room hidden" data-pane="Public">
      <ol id="Public_msgOl" class="chat__messages">
        <li><strong class="msg">dodo : </strong>Hi there!</li>
      </ol>
    </div>

  <div id="Sports_room" class="room" data-pane="Sports">
    <ol id="Public_msgOl" class="chat__messages">
      <li><strong class="msg">dodo : </strong>Whats up?</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
<!--/rooms-->
</div>
```

Comment: Well `activeTab` did not work here because it gets data attached to `body` of the page. Obviously it does not work on SO page where there is no data attached to body. However I added your modification to the snippet to avoid further confusions.

Comment: I updated my answer to explain what your mistake was.

Comment: Actually the order of `'` and `"` should be other way round, like `$('.rooms div[id!="' + newActiveTab + '_room"]').addClass("hidden");` but I accept as you point to the right direction. Thanks!